# Uncountable set from Riemann integral

Tags: integration

I have the following problem

> Let $f\geq 0$ and Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$. If 
>   $$\int_a^b f=0 $$
>   then the set of point $x\in [a,b]$ such that $f(x)=0$ is not countable.

I'd like some hint to solve it.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you know any theorems about the set of discontinuities of a Riemann integrable function?

Comment: No. I should not use nothing about measure. (measure if and only if discontinuities of a Riemann integrable function, in my mind.

Comment: OK, then @user2566092 (great name) gives you the right approach.

Comment: Can you give me some approach with measure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Lebesgue's criterion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_integral#Integrability) for Riemann integrability is that the set of discontinuities of $f$ must be a set of *measure zero*. Suppose that the set of points $x$ with $f(x)=0$ is countable. (Points of information: Every countable set is a set of measure zero. And the complement in $[a,b]$ of a set of measure zero cannot have measure zero.) Then there must be a point $x_0\in (a,b)$ (indeed lots of such points) with the properties that $f(x_0)>0$ and $f$ is continuous at $x_0$. By the definition of continuity, there is an interval $I=[x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta]$ with the property that $f(x)\ge c>0$ for all $x\in I$. It now follows that $$\int_a^b f \ge \int_{x_0-\delta}^{x_0+\delta} f \ge 2c\delta>0,$$
contradicting our hypothesis.